# Defining FromJSON on URI

Tags: haskell, aeson

Using [Network-URI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-URI.html) and Aeson, I defined the following `FROMJson URI`.

In short, I'm trying to implement a JSON Decoder requiring:

`{ "value" : X }` where `X` is a JSON String that evaluates to `Just` for [parseURI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-URI.html)(`X`).

```
instance FromJSON URI where
    parseJSON = withObject "URI" $ \v ->
      case Data.HashMap.Lazy.lookup "value" v of
        Just (String str) -> let unpacked = T.unpack str in
          case parseURI unpacked of
            Just uri -> pure uri
            Nothing  -> fail $ "String:" ++ unpacked ++ "is not a valid URI."
        Just value        -> typeMismatch "value" value
        Nothing           -> fail $ "JSON object does not have 'value' key."
```

However, for a valid `URI`, my code isn't working:

```
λ: >parseURI "http://www.foo.com"
Just http://www.foo.com

λ: >toJSON $ URI "http" Nothing "//www.foo.com" "" ""
String "http//www.foo.com"

λ: >fromJSON $ toJSON $ URI "http" Nothing "//www.foo.com" "" ""
Error "expected (), encountered String"
```

How can I fix my `FromJSON` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instance expects a JSON object of shape `{ "value": "url" }`, but the `toJSON` instance you're using obviously produces a plain string, as your interactive output clearly indicates.

For the last expression in your interactive session to work, you need to make `To` and `From` instances symmetrical: either make the `ToJSON` instance produce an object `{ "value": "url" }` or make the `FromJSON` instance expect a plain string.

Also, as an aside, your instance could be expressed in a much shorter way using the `.:` operator:

```
instance FromJSON URI where
    parseJSON = withObject "URI" $ \v -> do
        mUri <- parseURI . T.unpack <$> v .: "value"
        maybe (fail "Bad URI") pure mUri
```